# How to send data from server to html page without a request

Tags: html, servlets, web

I'm in the process of building my first site, so far I figures out how to make ajax calls to request data from servlets.

Now I need to make a notification system, in which the html page may receive data from the server without requesting it. (such as private messages or updates)

I'm not asking for code, I just want to know what I need to search and learn next in order to implement my requirement. I tried google-ing it but didn't find anything.

Comment: web sockets, Server-Sent Events, long polling. But that's raw terms. For ASP.NET looks at SignalR, for node.js at socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making requests, you'll have to use something like web sockets, long polling, etc. A easy to use open source option would be socket.io, or if it's a small project pubnub or pusher have worked well for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you might have a look at is node.js.

node js is a serverdriven javascript framework which allows to fire events.

http://nodejs.org/api/events.html